# Empty output when I check if c%d != 0

Tags: java

I am writing my first program but there is a part that I am struggling with:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    int c;
    int d;

    c = rand.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
    d = rand.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;

    if (c%d != 0 ) {
      c = rand.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
      d = rand.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
    } else {
      System.out.println(c);
      System.out.println(d);
      System.out.println(c / d);
    }        
  }
}
```

I'm checking only this part of my code in browxy.com so I don't have to reload my whole project over and over again in the android studio and the problem is that it sometimes do what I want it to do but more often it returns nothing. Just an empty black screen and I can't figure out why...

Comment: Format code as code please.

Comment: I don't see anywhere `a%b != 0` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code that is able to print something is in the `else{}` part of your `if-else` statement. So if `c%d != 0` condition is fulfilled, you only assign new values to `c` and `d`, as part in the first {...} is performed (you don't have any `System.out.println()` inside it).

Look:

```
if (c%d != 0) {
    // c = ...
    // d =...
    // You can use System.out.println() to print something to console
    // if condition is fulfilled, to make sure it works as you expect it to
} else {
    // System.out.println() prints something to console
    // if condition is not fulfilled
}
```

*By the way, I strongly suggest you to improve formatting of your code, it will help you and us all here quickly find out what the problem is.*

Second thing - it seems that the better idea is to use do-while loop that checks c and d until it finds suitable pair and prints result **AFTER** if-else statement:

```
do {
    c = rand.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
    d = rand.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
} while (c%d != 0);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(c / d);
```

Comment: I see!! I can't believe it was that obvious, I've been looking at this for 40min and couldn't firgure this out... Thank you man!

Answer (score 0):

`c%d != 0` implies, it will be `true` when `c` and `d` are not completely divisible, else `false` when they are completely divisible.

> Empty output when I check if c%d != 0

That probably because, *`c` and `d` are not completely divisible* (`c` and `d` are random number) and you aren't printing for such condition in `if` block.

You should move `System.out.println(c / d);` from `else` block to outside `if-else`

Answer (score 0):

In must cases it returns nothing because in must cases the condition `c%d!=0` is fulfilled which means you only assign values to c and d but do not print them

I think what you want to do is to assign a new value to c and d then recheck whether the condition is fulfilled and repeat this until c iis divisible by d

if you are familiar with loops you should put a while loop instead of the condition and after the while loop you ask the program to output c and d when c is divisible by d like the following:

```
while (c%d != 0 ) {

     c = rand.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
     d = rand.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;

     } 

     System.out.println(c);
     System.out.println(d);
     System.out.println(c / d);
```